# Jar-файлы не открываются

Tags: java, jar

Начал изучать java. Поставил eclipse.  Все работало, программы исполнялись.

Решил создать исполняемый файл, получил *.jar.
Запускаю его,а он не запускается. Запускаю его явно-"открыть с помощью java(TM) platform SE binary". А он ведет себя, как будто я его и не открывал. Просто остается в том же виде.

Пробовал запускать сторонние jar файлы. результат такой же.

---

стоит windows 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитай [вот эту статью](http://skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html). Я даю голову наотрез, что после внимательного ознакомления с указанной статьей расставятся все точки над `i`.

Answer (score 5):

В консоле

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

[`JAR`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR) - не является исполняемым файлом сам по себе

Comment: Да, называть все своими именами, то это не исполняемый файл, а архив(на сколько я понял). Но для того, что бы лучше передать свои намерения я назвал это исполняемым файлом.